# sails.socket testing with npm test

Tags: javascript, sockets, testing, sails.js

I'm using sails.js v0.11.0 and I am just getting into unit testing.  I can test normal controllers through http requests, but I have no idea where to start to test the same calls over a socket requests. If you have a good resource or a sample test using sockets that would be fantastic.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('supertest');

describe('Auth Controller', function () {

  describe('#callback()', function () {

    it ('passport-local authentication should succeed if email and password valid', function (done) {

      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .post('/auth/local')
        .send({
          identifier: 'existing.user@email.com',
          password: 'admin1234'
        })
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err) {
          done(err);
        });

    });

    it ('passport-local authentication should fail and return error code if email is invalid', function (done) {

      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .post('/auth/local')
        .send({
          identifier: 'invalid@email.com',
          password: 'admin1234'
        })
        .expect(403)
        .end(function(err) {
          done(err);
      });

    });

    it ('passport-local authentication should fail and return error code if password is invalid', function (done) {

      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .post('/auth/local')
        .send({
          identifier: 'existing.user@email.com',
          password: 'invalid1235'
        })
        .expect(403)
        .end(function(err) {
          done(err);
      });

    });

    //Test with Web Sockets from sails.io
    describe('sails.socket', function () {

      describe('With default settings', function() {

        describe('once connected, socket', function () {

          it ('passport-local authentication via web socket should succeed if email and password valid', function (done) {

            //Socket version?
            request(sails.hooks.http.app)
              .post('/auth/local')
              .send({
                identifier: 'existing.user@email.com',
                password: 'admin1234'
              })
              .expect(200)
              .end(function(err) {
                done(err);
              });

          });

          it ('passport-local authentication via web socket should fail and return error code if email is invalid', function (done) {

            //Socket version?
            request(sails.hooks.http.app)
              .post('/auth/local')
              .send({
                identifier: 'invalid@email.com',
                password: 'admin1234'
              })
              .expect(403)
              .end(function(err) {
                done(err);
              });

          });

          it ('passport-local authentication via web socket should fail and return error code if password is invalid', function (done) {

            //Socket version?
            request(sails.hooks.http.app)
              .post('/auth/local')
              .send({
                identifier: 'existing.user@email.com',
                password: 'invalid1235'
              })
              .expect(403)
              .end(function(err) {
                done(err);
            });

          });

        });

      });
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't claim credit for this, but incase you've stumbled upon this question and are looking for the answer here it is.

Declare io as a global in the bootstrap:

```
// test/boostrap.test.js

var client = require('../assets/js/dependencies/sails.io.js');

global.io = new client(require('socket.io-client'));
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337/';
```

Then call them use them like so.

```
//test/callbacks.test.js
describe('socket request', function () {

 it ('passport-local authentication should succeed if email and password valid', function (done) {

  io.socket.post('/auth/local', { identifier: 'existing.user@email.com', password: 'admin1234' }, function (data, jwres) {
  assert.equal(jwres.statusCode, 200);
  done();  
 });
});
```

Comment: When i run this, I get: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Comment: Hi Scott, is this the recommended way? Or is the way Tyler mentioned the way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38819560/1828637 ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to use cookies for me. I'm logged in but i keep getting unauthorized response.

Answer (score 2):

I found that Sails has what I'd consider good documentation on this subject, but *not* directly in their [normal Sails documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets) on the subject (although it's good general knowledge material to have read first). Instead, I had to read their [github sails.io.js project](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js). Again, better than the README there is their example. Look in [this file](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/blob/b6a5cbf3624dbcc875f4dc3349d94835afbd8387/test/helpers/lifecycle.js) to see their setup and teardown for testing sockets, and [this file](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/commit/327994c9d0c5d59451717105342a2322947a1ce5#diff-3e83410f9bacd2afa7fe9364062f1283) that shows off the tests themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the Response!